# Is there any difference between specflow's .msi installer and its nuget package?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, nuget, specflow, acceptance-testing

[On specflow's own instalation guide](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Installation) it says that the only way to install it is using the .msi installer and most of the tutorials I've read on the subject tell me to download and install said file but when I search on the nuget package manager I find there's also an available package for specflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is in the tooling. With the MSI you get full item template, syntax coloring  and intellisense support in the IDE where as with the NuGet you just get the code generation and runtime support. So I'd say 9 times out of 10 if you're going to be doing any serious work with it you're going to want the MSI for those rich features.

At this point they really should be offering it as a Visual Studio Extension for a lot more integrated install experience using VS Extension Manager.